# Trouble for logining in to Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I'm finding a trouble in root local host login in Ubuntu . I am using Ubuntu for the first time in my new laptop Acer aspire 5 A515-51 how could I over come it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to login to root user, you need to login with local user first. You must be able login using your standard user credentials. After your login is successful with standard user, just open the terminal ( type CTRL+ALT+T to open terminal) and type

*sudo su*

Hit enter and it will ask you for password, enter the same password you used for login and it's done.
You will have successfully logged in as root.

Comment: This was the first time I'm loging in to Ubuntu

Comment: Root login using GUI is disabled in Ubuntu. You should have standard user login credentials in order to login

Answer (score 0):

You cannot login as root in Ubuntu. If you want to execute commands with root privileges use sudo.
If you require root shell use

> su -

Comment: That was not even working

Comment: what error you are getting?